# Multiple IF with one ELSE

Tags: algorithm, syntax, if-statement

I would like to consider one syntax improvement.

How I can write this better:

```
IF condition1 
    IF condition2
        { do something }
    ELSE 
        { message1 }
ELSE 
    { message1 }
```

There are two IF statements that cannot be joined in one statement, but in both ELSE parts need to be same code (in this example message1).

How this can be written better? I wouldn't like to write same code (in ELSE parts) twice.

TnX in advance!

Nemanja

Comment: In what language are you working?

Comment: `IF condition1 AND condition2 ... ELSE message1`?

Comment: "cannot be joined in one statement" - why?

Comment: @alestanis Language is not important. I need general answer, pseudo-code.

Comment: @BartKiers - That seems like the obvious answer, but the "cannot be joined in one statement" part is confusing me

Comment: @Yakk It cannot be joined because I would like to consider wider example (with more nested IF statements with different code, but here wrote just two because of simplification).

Comment: @NemanjaVujacic, then it's better to provide some real example, instead of an over-simplified one.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, ah, is that what the OP meant by that...

Answer (score 6):

The obvious solution is to combine the two conditions:

```
IF condition1 AND condition2
    { do something }
ELSE 
    { message1 }
```

However if the two conditions really can not be combined for some reason, and you are using a C-like language which has a `break` keyword or equivalent, then you can do something like this:

```
DO
   IF condition1
      IF condition2
          { do something }
          BREAK
   { message1 }
WHILE FALSE
```

Comment: two IF statements that cannot be joined in one statement

Comment: OK, but it would help if you explained *why* you have this constraint ? Anyway, see edit above for alternate solution.

Answer (score 4):

What about

```
IF condition1 AND condition2
    { do something }
ELSE 
    { message1 }
```

If you can't join both statements, you can use some sort of GOTO (ps: this is bad practice)

```
IF condition1 
    IF condition2
        { do something }
    ELSE 
        GOTO ELSE_CODE
ELSE 
    :ELSE_CODE
    { message1 }
```

Comment: I need solution without joining both statements, and, as you said, solution with pointer to another part of code is not good practice.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this bad practice, but one of the rare cases where a `goto` (if the jump isn't unreasibly far in the code) yields simpler, shorter and more understandable code - especially compared with `do ... while (false)` hacks.

Comment: This answer is exactly the opposite from the actual question.

Answer (score 3):

in case you're talking about a language without short-circuit boolean evaluation, you could manually implement it like

```
flag = condition1 
IF flag
    flag = flag AND condition2
IF flag
    { do something }
ELSE 
    { message1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched for this answer and I realized you just need to reorder the statements.

Instead of 2 IF statements with one else like this

```
{
     if(FirstCheck === true){
         //run function 1
     }
     if(SecondCheck === true){
         //run function 2
      }
}else{
    //run this else only when the first 2 IFs are false
    // run function 3        
     }
}
```

you want to do a IF for the reason why you want to run the function in the else, and then put an else for that IFs, that then runs your original IFs

```
if(orginalElse !== true){
    //run function 3
    //this is the orginal else you would want to run, just with a negative if statement
}else{
    if(FirstCheck === true){
        //run function 1
    }
    if(SecondCheck === true){
        //run function 2
    }
}
```